# How can alter color of mat-label

Tags: html, angular, frontend

I need to alter color of my mat-label.
But when I try to alter color with `!important` in scss, I get error in my input.... the color doesn't revert back to red.

I need to just alter the color of label if I don't get error, if I get error It should be left with red color.

```html
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always" appearance="none">
  <mat-label>Usuário</mat-label>
  <input autofocus matInput formControlName="j_username">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

just change color you like in scss

```
mat-label {
color: red;
}
```